# Using SSDT to do reverse engineering so I can get overview of schema just like in MySQL

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, schema, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I just installed and imported my database in Visual Studio , All I  want to see is schema to get a quick relation of among different tables , I was hoping if I could get a way to do the same in SQL server just like it can be done with my sql reverse engineering

I use Azure data studio (the extension  is buggy ), I also have Sql server manangement studio , I also visual studio and selected database management pack where SSDT was included and now I simply imported the database which I want schema for

Answer (score 0):

SSMS has some rudimentary diagram tools to pull in objects and see any relations that exist. Something to watch for is that if you add any relations or modify anything other than the layout on that diagram, you actually change the database itself.

There are some free/cheap ERD apps/sites that you may want to investigate and many will give you a script to run in SQL Server to extract the schema in a format they can use.

I'd recommend searching on ERD apps that can do database diagrams, but for a free option you may want to check out https://dbschema.com/ (there's a free/trial version) or https://dbdiagram.io as they can handle some simple ER diagrams. (note - no affiliation to either, just some examples/options)

You can't easily forward-engineer changes with it, but it can work to just see the relationships visually.  If you're going to use ER diagrams regularly, a paid option will be much more helpful. There are a lot of options available, but for that sort of design work you probably want collaboration and the ability to push out changes to a live database from the ERD.